# JS promise or async await return as an object promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I know this has been asked a gazillion times.  I've asked it myself.  Specifically to the code below I don't know why this doesn't resolve.

```
const householdPics = (data, props) => {
  let refImg;

  async function refDetails() {
    let urlResult;
    const ref = await props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${data.profilePic}`);
    return urlResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ref.getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => resolve(url))
      .catch(e => reject(e))
    })
  }

  if (!data.profilePic || data.profilePic == 'NULL') {
    refImg = require("../../assets/img/empty-avatar.png");
  } else {
    refImg = refDetails();
  }
```

I'm sure I'm over complicating this, I've been at it so long I'm all confused myself.
I would expect `refImg = refDetails();` to resolve to a url.
if I console.log `urlResult` I get an img url from firebase.
However when I use refImg in another block of code:

src appears as Object Promise

I also tried:

```
  async function refDetails() {
    const ref = await props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${data.profilePic}`);
    const refUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return refUrl;
  }
```

Here is another attempt I've tried after reading up more on this.  Still failing :(

```
  let refImg;

  function refDetails() {
    const ref = props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${data.profilePic}`);
    const imgUrl = ref.getDownloadURL()
    return imgUrl.then(url => {return url})
  }

  if (!data.profilePic || data.profilePic == 'NULL') {
    refImg = require("../../assets/img/empty-avatar.png");
  } else {
    const resultImg = refDetails();;
    refImg = resultImg;
  }
```

How can I pass the return value of ref.getDownloadURL() to refImg?

Comment: `async` functions will always return a promise

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! And yes, you can't make `refImg` being anything else but a promise

Comment: I updated another example that still gives me the same thing.  @Bergi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
const householdPics = async (data, props) => {
  let refImg;

  async function refDetails() {
    let urlResult;
    const ref = await props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${data.profilePic}`);
    return await ref.getDownloadURL():
  }

  if (!data.profilePic || data.profilePic == 'NULL') {
    refImg = require("../../assets/img/empty-avatar.png");
  } else {
    refImg = await refDetails();
  }
```

## UPDATE:

`ref.getDownloadURL()` is a Promise and in order to use the result value, which is the url, you MUST get it inside the callback of `.then`, or you use `async await` syntax, which make async process seems to be synchronize like my previous answer did.

`imgUrl.then(url => {return url})` Promise.then() is also a Promise so you're still returning promise in the function in your second attempt. Therefore `refImg = resultImg` results in making `refImg` an "Promise returning a url".

The reason you think the previous answer doesn't work is probably that, you called `householdPics()` and try to get the value without using `.then` or `await`. Since I made `householdPics` an async function, it will always returns a Promise. So again, you have to get the value with `.then` or `await`.

## UPDATE 2

I just tried about **returning a Promise in async function**. It seems that if you return a Promise instead of resolved value in an async function like:

```js
async function refDetails() {
    let urlResult;
    const ref = await props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${data.profilePic}`);
    return ref.getDownloadURL():
  }
```

then await the function:

```js
refImg = await refDetails();
```

it still resolves and returns the value of the Promise. So you can save a that `await` in the async function if you're returning it (while I don't recommend it since it's quiet confusing).

Comment: still appears as an object promsie

Comment: Are you sure you've added await on both before ref.getDownloadUrl and refDetails at the last line?

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  I didn't downvote by the way.  @Hao-Cher Hong

Comment: No problem. That's weird. Could you describe how do you "use refImg in another block of code"?

Comment: Yes but that's not what's causing the problem.  I just posted another attempt in the question with out async await.  @Hao-Cher Hong

Comment: I've updated my answer and I think you should check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function to understand more about Promise and async function.